# How to make nifty gui textfield to use a larger font

Tags: gui, jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

Hi I have a text field on my screen but its tiny:

```
<panel height="13%" width="100%" childLayout="vertical">
    <text id="label1" height="50%" font="Interface/Fonts/MinionPro.fnt" color="#f00f"
          text="Hello World!" align="center" valign="center" />
</panel>
<panel height="10%" width="100%" backgroundColor="#55a5" childLayout="center">
    <control name="textfield" text="Some text"/>
</panel>
```

the problem is I can not figure out how to change the font size on it. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jME/Nifty, each letter is basically a Quad with a Texture on it. Scaling font-textures usually looks horrible and I guess that's why Nifty doesn't provide an option for scaling (you can scale `BitmapText` in jME though).

Easiest way is to generate a new, bigger font. If you're using the jME SDK there's a built-in generator. Right click on a folder in the Projects Window and choose `New -> Other -> GUI -> Font`.

I recommend a padding of 2 for X and Y. Otherwise you might see random dots in the rendered text (these are parts of other letters that are overlapping the letter box in the texture).

Sometimes there's a huge gap between the letters. You can control that by using negative values for "letter spacing".

---

Nifty's Textfield-Control is a composition of panels and text elements. To use a bigger font you have to redefine its style.
Grab the original `nifty-textfield.xml` from your `nifty-style-black.jar` or from here: https://github.com/nifty-gui/nifty-gui/blob/1.4/nifty-controls-style-black/src/main/resources/textfield/nifty-textfield.xml

Save it somewhere in your Assets/Interface folder and include it in your other XML like this:
(Make sure to include it *after* `nifty-default-styles.xml`)

```
<useStyles filename="Interface/textfield.xml" />
```

Now you have to adjust the style. Remove the `base="base-font"` attribute from the style with ID `nifty-textfield#text` and add `font` to the `attributes`-Tag.
It should look like this:

```
<style id="nifty-textfield#text">
    <attributes ... font="Interface/Fonts/YourFont-24.fnt" />
</style>
```

You probably also want to change the size of the Textfield to match the new font. Edit the other styles in this file as you need.

The Nifty Manual explains controls and styles in more detail:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nifty-gui/files/nifty-gui/1.3.2/nifty-gui-the-manual-1.3.2.pdf/download

Comment: Is there a way to apply this concept for multiple resolutions?

Comment: You could define multiple style sets - one for each resolution - all using the same names for the styles. Then check the resolution in java and add the appropriate style.xml with `Nifty.addXml()`. I think you could use the `base="base-style"` attribute so you only have to redefine the differences. Maybe this is useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265892/how-can-i-implement-auto-scale-feature-in-nifty-gui

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to resize fonts within a label, as pointed out in this [JMonkeyEngine forum post](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/changing-text-size-of-a-label-nifty-gui/13218).

> You can't currenty set the text size of a Label in Nifty. This is mainly due to the use of bitmap based fonts which usually don't resize very well. You need to use different fonts for best visual appearance if you need different text sizes.

Comment: but its not a label it text input, and on label I still able to set font but not on textfield

Comment: Same thing either way, though.

Comment: but how do I set font to it since I can do it for label, the font attribute did not work